# Will this question on collaboration be on topic?

Tags: discussion, collaboration

I ask this question on Academia.SE ([How can physicists help in theoretical biology, besides math and fresh perspectives?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/34941/how-can-physicists-help-in-theoretical-biology-besides-math-and-fresh-perspecti)) but it is decided to be off topic because it is ask for "the content of your research, rather than the process of doing research" as state in [its help center](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Because I would like to open it again, I want to move this question to Biology here. Will it be on topic? Two bullets of [what is off topic here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> - personal medical questions and health advice
> - philosophical or ethical questions related to biology

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question: "*How can physicists help in biology*" sounds too broad to me. There are physicists with different kinds of specialization. Instead of asking what can a physicist do in biology, IMO it is better to ask for examples where principles of physics have been applied to solve a biological problem.

You said you had worked in the area of biophysics. You can highlight some points that you found were interdisciplinary.

Also note that physicists have a training in mathematics and that also makes them capable of working on theoretical aspects of biology that may fall under the realm of theoretical chemistry/chemical engineering (rate equations etc).

So you should also clarify what areas of physics you are interested in; is it about application of principles of physics or just advantages of having a degree in physics?

If the question sounds like "*What are the career options for a physicist in a biology department*," then it would be considered off topic. Otherwise I shall consider this on-topic in biology SE, given it is not too broad.